# How read facebook timeline

Tags: php, facebook

I need to read facebook timeline but I don't know how I can do. I don't find anything!! I use this library:

https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk

Anyone can help me to suggest a tutorial or other something?

Comment: Facebook has developers manual.

Answer (score 1):

[Here you can access the FB Developer pages.](https://developers.facebook.com/)

They have examples and manuals for a variety of programming languages and tools.

Here's a few things you will need in order to read an FB timeline:

> Facebook assigns a unique and fairly long ID to any account, whether profile or fan page. Users, however, don’t use this ID to identify pages. So the first thing to do in order to read a timeline is match the public name of the page (or user) to the underlying Facebook ID.
>
> Getting the ID of the account for which you intend to read the timeline is only the first step. You also need to be authenticated to access the feed.
>
> Once acquired, the access token can be saved to a cookie and used for every further operation until it expires.

You can find the whole article on [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166925.aspx).

There are a few code examples on the page as well written in C#.

Hope this helps.